# How to redirect all non www and http traffic to www and https with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite

In my httpd.conf, I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But that's not working properly. I want the following to redirect to https://www.mysite.com:

- http://mysite.com
- https://mysite.com
- http://www.mysite.com

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's not working properly. But the following will work:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.com
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$        https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)           https://www.mysite.com/$1
```

This can be conceived as a duplicate post of many similar posts about rewrite rules on apache but I find this one particularly well worded about the redirect non-SSL so maybe this can be the last post that will need to be answered and people will be able to find that one easier!

Comment: do i need the `=mysite.com` or just `mysite.com`

Comment: I believe either way works. I have it with the equal sign but examples in Apache docs seems to show it without.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1`

Doesn't seem to redirect to HTTPS

Comment: I fail to see how what you wrote in your comment here matches what I suggested. And what does not redirect? http://www.mysite.com/ or http://mysite.com/ or both?

Comment: both. I went a slightly different route for SSL